# Variables not available in callback?

Tags: javascript

I'm looping through some results and saving them in a MongoDB.

```
let newSaved = 0
let dupes = 0

items.forEach(d => {
  let newItem = new Item({ ...d })

  newItem.save(err => {
    if (err) {
      dupes += 1
      page = null
    } else {
      newSaved += 1
    }
  })
})

console.log(`Finished page ${page}`)
console.log(`New: ${newSaved} - Dupes: ${dupes}`)
```

The final `console.log` always outputs `newSaved` and `dupes` as zero. I'm sure it's a scope thing and perhaps it's just my pre-caffeinated brain missing out on something normal. Any insight?

Comment: It seems that Item.prototype.save() is async, so the console.logs are executed first

Comment: Is your `newItem.save` async? If so then your `forEach` is likely ending before all the saves

Comment: Another post that might help: [Using async/await with a forEach loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37576685/using-async-await-with-a-foreach-loop)